# Custom "compare" and axis range in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I added a custom "compare" routine in order to compute the difference of some point value relative to the previous point (instead of relative to the first point in the series as implemented in *compare: 'value'*):

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Series.prototype, "setCompare", function(proceed, compare) {
  // Set or unset the modifyValue method
  this.modifyValue = (compare === 'value' || compare === 'percent' || compare === 'value_previous' || compare === 'percent_previous') ?
    function(value, point) {
    
      // MODIFIED ---------------------
      var compareValue;
      if (point && compare.includes("_previous")) {
        compareValue = point.series.processedYData[point.index - 1];
      } else {
        compareValue = this.compareValue;
      }
      // -------------------------------

      if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && typeof compareValue !== 'undefined') { // #2601, #5814
        // Get the modified value
        if (compare.includes('value')) { // MODIFIED!!!!!!!
          value -= compareValue;
          // Compare percent
        } else {
          value = 100 * (value / compareValue) - (this.options.compareBase === 100 ? 0 : 100);
        }
        // record for tooltip etc.
        if (point) {
          point.change = value;
        }
        return value;
      }
      return 0;
    } :
    null;
  // Survive to export, #5485
  this.userOptions.compare = compare; // ---WHAT TO DO???---
  // Mark dirty
  if (this.chart.hasRendered) {
    this.isDirty = true;
  }
});
```

The chart is drawn as expected (see fiddle), but the yaxis' range does not cover the new computed values. Any idea how to solve the problem?
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/x4ckroyp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also include this part of the code which will trigger and get the `this.modifyValue` from your custom wrap.

```
///
/// MISSED FUNCTIONS
///

var arrayMin = Highcharts.arrayMin = function arrayMin(data) {
    var i = data.length, min = data[0];
    while (i--) {
        if (data[i] < min) {
            min = data[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
};

var arrayMax = Highcharts.arrayMax = function arrayMax(data) {
    var i = data.length, max = data[0];
    while (i--) {
        if (data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
};

// Modify series extremes
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Series.prototype, 'afterGetExtremes', function (e) {
    var dataExtremes = e.dataExtremes;
    if (this.modifyValue && dataExtremes) {
        var extremes = [
            this.modifyValue(dataExtremes.dataMin),
            this.modifyValue(dataExtremes.dataMax)
        ];
        dataExtremes.dataMin = arrayMin(extremes);
        dataExtremes.dataMax = arrayMax(extremes);
    }
});


///
///
///
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ucvae7xy/

Comment: Thanks for the response! The answer required a little bit more code, but you pointed me to the right track. Now it supports several options for compare, including a "cumulative". See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/shp6ukfj/)